# Elasticsearch filter on aggregation

Tags: database, nosql, elasticsearch

Since I couldn't find anything on Google:

Is it possible to filter on an aggregation in elasticsearch. Im thinking of someting like: Get all objects where SUM(obect.X) > 100.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT - Sample Data**

I have the following document-structure:

```
{
  docKey : 1
  value: 2
},
{
  docKey: 1
  value: 5
},
{
  docKey:1
  value: 7
},
{
  docKey:2
  value:2
},...
```

I now want to query the docKey from the database where the sum of the value is bigger than X.

**EDIT2**

I found out that is something I have to do in my application logic. 
you can see it [here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Faceting-and-filter-on-aggregated-values-td4037680.html)

Comment: Can you please post some code, some data and your expected result? The question you are asking is vague

Comment: i hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but seeing as you were pretty vague i.e. posting no mapping, query or anything of that matter we can't help you. However I hope you'll be able to work it out for yourself with [this](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-aggregations/) fantastic article on aggregations. Best of luck.

**Update** - Maybe [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-statistical-facet.html) is what you're looking for instead?

Comment: i just want to know if something like this is possible with one query at all. Thanks for the article but it does not answere my question :(