# Elasticsearch filter on aggregation result (for search and aggregation)

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

Part of this question is related to : [Elasticsearch filter on aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107995/elasticsearch-filter-on-aggregation)

**Context**

Let's say my Elasticsearch index contains some orders. Each order has one field price and one field amount. This result in an index that look like this :

```
[
  {
    "docKey": "order01",
    "user": "1",
    "price": 8,
    "amount": 20
  },
  {
    "docKey": "order02",
    "user": "1",
    "price": 14,
    "amount": 3
  },
  {
    "docKey": "order03",
    "user": "2",
    "price": 5,
    "amount": 1
  },
  {
    "docKey": "order04",
    "user": "2",
    "price": 10,
    "amount": 3
  }
]
```

**What I would like to do**

What I want to do is a filter on some values aggregated per user. I want to do this kind of filter for search and also in order to apply aggregation on it. For example in this example I would like to retrieve the documents of all user that have their average order with a price in the range of 9-14.

User 1 has an average price order of 11 so we keep both of his orders.
User 2 has an average price order of 7.5 so both his orders are not kept.

This was the easy part. After I filter to only get the user one. I want to do some more aggregates on the result.

So for example : I want the repartition of the average per user of the amout field among the bucket [0,10] and [10,20] for all user that have an average order with a price in the range of 9-14.

The answer I except for this question is 0 in the bucket [0,10] and one in the bucket [10,20] (Only user 1 is kept because of his average price. His average amount is 11.5 so in the bucket [10,20]).

**What I have tried**

I have manage do to my filter in order to retrieve the users that have their average order with a price in the range of 9-14. I did this by first doing a term aggregation on the user filed. Then I do a subaggregation that is an avg aggregation on the price. Then I do a bucket selector pipeline aggregation that check if the previous computed average price is between 9 and 14.

I have also manage to do the aggregation I wanted but without the previous filter. I did exactly the same thing that for the filter for each range. Then I count the number of results in each bucket.

I havn't find any way to apply an other aggregation on bucket selector result. So i could not first do the filter and then apply the range...

Also theses solution are not elegant.. I don't think they will scale up as a big part of the document need to be returned in the answer and processed further (even if it's off internet I prefer avoiding doing this and I might be limited in the result size of an aggregation ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find a solution but it's not elegant and might be poorly scalable.

- Make a term aggregation on the user.
- As a sub-aggregation of the term aggregation do an avg aggregation that compute the average of the price.
- As a sub-aggregation of the term aggregation do an avg aggregation that compute the average of the amount.
- Do a bucket selector pipeline aggregation that filter to only keep avg_price in range [9-14].
- Do a bucket selector pipeline aggregation that filter to only keep avg_amount in a [0-10]
- Do a "count" bucket script pipeline aggregation (with script returning one).
- Do a bucket sum pipeline aggregation that sum the count.
- Repeat all the steps for all ranges wanted ([0-10], [10-20])

Comment: Complicated i don't know... But not ideal for sure. Do you have a better solution ?